# How do I get Hangouts to work on a straight talk optiumus showtime?

Tags: google-hangouts, apn

Phone Model Number: LGL86C

PRL Version: 59377

Andriod version: 4.0.4

Kernel version: 3.0.8

Software version: L86CV10a

I have called straight talk wireless and they told me that my model phone does not have an APN setting. Does anyone know how to get around this so I can use hangouts as my main message sending app? I use it for everything and I cannot send MMS messages without configuring the APN settings.